# "Not assignable" error on creating reusable Button component, even on providing custom enum for type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm creating a custom `Button` element in a React + TS project, but when I declare the Props `type` I receive the following error:

```
Type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>' is not assignable to type '"button" | "reset" | "submit" | undefined'.ts(2322)

index.d.ts(2086, 9): The expected type comes from property 'type' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>'
```

I'm aware that there's an [identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59494887/creating-reusable-button-component-with-react-and-typescript-with-not-assignable) (and I actually tried its solution by creating a custom `enum`), but I still get the same error. I also tried using the type suggested in the error itself, as well as the types suggested in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/36505), to no avail.

Given that both resources are over 2 years old, I'm wondering if something changed in that time or even if it's an issue to be tuned in my `.tsconfig` file.

```js
import React from 'react';

enum ButtonTypes {
    'button',
    'submit',
    'reset',
    undefined
}

type Props = {
    text: string;
    type: React.ComponentProps<'button'>; // ButtonTypes throws the same error
    onClick: Function | null;
};

function Button({ text, type, onClick }: Props) {
    return (
        <button
            className='className="bg-primary text-base-100 font-display font-light self-center mt-5 px-3 py-2"'
            type={type}
        >
            {text}
        </button>
    );
}

export default Button;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally Im surprised that the answer your mentioned is the *approved* one, because it still does throw ts errors for me.

Using the `ButtonTypes` enum as:

```
enum ButtonTypes {
  "button",
  "submit",
  "reset",
  undefined
}
```

resolves to:

```
enum ButtonTypes {
  "button" = 0,
  "submit" = 1,
  "reset" = 2,
  undefined = 3
}
```

and of course it's incorrect because `button` does not expect button type as `0` o `1`.

However after setting the values for enum fields:

```
enum ButtonTypes {
  Button = 'button',
  Submit = 'submit',
  Reset = 'reset',
}
```

It works correctly.

**Note**: remember to change the `type` prop type to `ButtonTypes`.

```
type Props = {
    text: string;
    type?: ButtonTypes;
    onClick: Function | null;
};
```

**Note2**: using *enum* is not necessary anyways, you can always extend your type with default button props.

```
type Props = {
  text: string;
  onClick: Function | null;
} & ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>;
```

Comment: Thanks! I did thought that enum was weird, but I'm not very familiar with TS yet. I'll certainly check the extend option as well!